# Copy files from s3 bucket to ec2 instance using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a bashscript present in S3 bucket.i need to run that bashscript in my EC2 instance using python.

I tried using ssm but it is not working.

```
 params={
'sourceType': ['S3'],
'path': ['https://test-bucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/testscript.sh'],
'commands' : ['sh testscript.sh'],
}

testCommand = ssm_client.send_command( InstanceIds=[ InstanceId], DocumentName='AWS-RunShellScript', Parameters= params)
```

Can someone please help me solving this issue

Comment: Do you have the SSM agent installed to your machine?

Comment: From where are you running the command? If from the same EC2, why not download and then execute?

Answer (score 0):

Try by the following method, add the below in your command document

```
---
schemaVersion: "2.2"
description: "Command Document Example JSON Template"
parameters:
  Message:
    type: "String"
    description: "Run command through S3"
    default: "Run command through S3"
mainSteps:
- action: "aws:runShellScript"
  name: "s3commandexecution"
  inputs:
    runCommand:
    - curl -L https://test-bucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/testscript.sh > testscript.sh
    - ./testscript.sh
```

Then run your command through python boto3

```
testCommand = ssm_client.send_command( InstanceIds=[ InstanceId], DocumentName='AWS-RunShellScript')
```